# Prevent neovim from overwriting system clipboard while cutting, copying or deleting text

Tags: neovim, os-clipboard

As the title says, I want to disable `neovim` from overwriting existing content of my clipboard. I am using `elementary os 7 horus` and `nvim v0.10.0-dev-115+g240c41e1a` downloaded from github release page. I am fairly new to vim. If I want to copy to system clipboard I would use `"+y`. But, when I cut or copy text using `x`, `d` or `y` it just overwrites my clipboard. I saw some solutions on the internet. But those entirely disables clipboard. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to unset `clipboard`

```
set clipboard=
```

Then the default register `"` is used for the operations (`x`, `c`, `y`, `d`) and to use the system clipboard you have to specify the `+` or `*` register.

Comment: that same thing did not work on manjaro. But, working on elementary. Weird!